# Antenna Design in relation to RLC circuit

Tags: antenna

I am having trouble understanding how antennas can be "represented" as an RLC circuit; how do these two concepts, antenna design and RLC circuits, relate to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain antenna types like dipoles and microstrip patches are effectively leaky resonators. They support a standing wave at single frequency and have relatively narrow bandwidth (high Q), just like an RLC circuit. The same way an RLC circuit loses energy to the resistive element, antennas lose energy to radiation. At its resonant frequency, an antenna like this has a purely real input impedance. Changing the dimensions of the antenna changes its resonant frequency. This is analogous to the frequency of standing waves on strings being inversely proportional to the length of the string.

The image below from http://www.radartutorial.eu/06.antennas/Microstrip%20Antenna.en.html is a good example with a patch antenna. The patch antenna supports a 1/2 wavelength standing wave. The patch has fringing fields coming off its radiating edge that create the propagating EM fields.

The difference between an RLC circuit and a patch antenna, is that a patch antenna can support several resonant modes. This is because it is a 2D structure. It can resonant along its length, or its width, or even diagonally. This can be represented by multiple RLC circuits representing the different resonant modes. It is usually not desirable, and the antenna is designed to only resonate at 1 mode.

Some patch antennas are implemented with high \$\kappa\$ dielectrics to reduce the size of a wavelength and the antenna. The consequence of making the dielectric constant too high is that the fields do not fringe, the antenna doesn't radiate, and it becomes just a resonator.

[image]